# MLE of an exponential distribution with constant

Tags: exponential-distribution, maximum-likelihood

I have a pdf given as,

$$
\begin{equation}
\nonumber \mathcal{p_\lambda}(x) = \left\{
\begin{array}{l l}
ae^{-\lambda (x - b)} & \quad x \geq b\\
0 & \quad \textrm{if } x < b
\end{array} \right.
\end{equation}
$$

How do I calculate its MLE?

I've tried doing it. And this is what I ended up with:
$$
\lambda_{MLE} = \prod_{i = 1}^{n}f_X(x_i; \lambda) = \prod_{i = 1}^{n} \bigl\{{ae^{-\lambda(x_i - b)}}\bigr\} \\
L(\lambda) = ae^{-n\lambda((x_1 + x_2 + ... + x_n) - b)}\\
\log L(\lambda) = \log (a) - \lambda x log(e) + \lambda b \log(e) \\
\text{Taking derivative on both sides,} \\
\frac{d}{d\lambda} \{\log L(\lambda)\} = \frac{d}{d\lambda} \{\log (a) - \lambda x log(e) + \lambda b \log(e)\} \\
\Rightarrow b - \bar x \\
$$
Now I know that I have to equate the derivative to 0 to get MLE, but there's no $\lambda $ to get the $\lambda_{MLE}$. How shall I proceed? Am I doing something wrong?
Please, help!

Comment: So $\lambda = \min_i x_i$ is the answer I'm looking for?

Comment: Not exactly, the difference between your question and the one suggested by @callculus42 is that in that question the log-likelihood function is an increasing function of the parameter $\theta$, but in your case it is decreasing, so you do not get a maximum (maximum is at $-\infty$). There is something wrong here .. are you sure that $a$ is a constant and not a function of $\lambda$

Comment: Yes. Even I thought the same. It has to be a function of $\lambda$ but it's not. It's a constant $a$. It's straight from my assignment question!